# Como definir uma variável na configuração de um Virtual Host, para evitar repetição?

Tags: virtualhost, apache

Eu sempre fico chateado quando vejo que meu virtualhost acaba sendo configurado dessa forma:

```
<VirtualHost :80>

    ServerName meusite.local
    ServerAlias www.meusite.local


    DocumentRoot /var/www/meusite/public

    ErrorLog /var/www/meusite/__apache__.log

</VirtualHost>
```

Note que eu repeti o `/var/www/meusite/` duas vezes ali e, considerando que eu pudesse ter mais configurações que usasse essa mesma pasta raiz, poderia ser um saco fazer isso.

Eu queria saber se tem alguma forma de salvar essa `/var/www/meusite` numa variável e usá-la, concatenando com `/public` e `__apache__.log`, por exemplo.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Core do apache existe o `Define`, conforme a documentação: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#Define

É usado para definir variáveis

```
Define root_dir /var/www/meusite

<VirtualHost :80>    
    ServerName meusite.local
    ServerAlias www.meusite.local

    DocumentRoot ${root_dir}/public

    ErrorLog ${root_dir}/__apache__.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Em multiplos hosts:

```
Define root_dir1 /var/www/meusite1
Define root_dir2 /var/www/meusite2

<VirtualHost meusite1.local:80>
    ServerAlias www.meusite2.local

    DocumentRoot ${root_dir1}/public

    ErrorLog ${root_dir1}/__apache__.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost meusite2.local:80>
    ServerAlias www.meusite2.local

    DocumentRoot ${root_dir2}/public

    ErrorLog ${root_dir2}/__apache__.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Vale notar que se você usa muitos "includes" talvez volta e meia possa acidentalmente acabar conflintando, e incluir algo duas vezes, neste caso você pode usar o `<IfDefined>` para checar se um arquivo ou se uma variavel já foi definida

```
<IfDefine !FOO>
Include Foo.config
</IfDefine>
```

Neste exemplo claro que dentro de `Foo.config` deve existir algo como:

```
Define FOO valor
```

Além de definir é possivel remover uma variavel, assim:

```
<IfDefine FOO>
UnDefine FOO
</IfDefine>
```

---

É bom ressaltar este trecho da documentação:

> **Virtual Host scope and pitfalls**
>
> While this directive is supported in virtual host context, the changes
>   it makes are visible to any later configuration directives, beyond any
>   enclosing virtual host.

Traduzindo:

> O escopo do Virtual Host e sua armadilhas
>
> Embora essa diretiva seja suportada no contexto do Virtual Host, as alterações feitas são visíveis para qualquer outra diretiva de configuração posterior, além de qualquer outro Virtual Host incluído.

Comment: Curiosidade: essas variáveis são definidas apenas no escopo do arquivo virtual host ou é global?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters infelizmente fica no escopo global. Resposta atualizada.

Answer (score 2):

Pode utilizar a directiva Define

Ver documento em https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#define

```
Define pasta /var/www/meusite/


<VirtualHost :80>

    ServerName meusite.local
    ServerAlias www.meusite.local


    DocumentRoot ${pasta}public

    ErrorLog ${pasta}__apache__.log

</VirtualHost>
```